# Libgdx Orthographic Camera initial position

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

I would like the camera to be positioned correctly but I am getting the result below:

[image]

It seems like when I resize the window, the map does not get rendered properly. Why does that happen?

Code:

```
public void render(float delta){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    mapRenderer.setView(camera);
    mapRenderer.render(background);
    mapRenderer.render(foreground);
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    //draw rectangles around walls
    for(MapObject object : tiledMap.getLayers().get("walls").getObjects()){
        if(object instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
            RectangleMapObject rectObject = (RectangleMapObject) object;
            Rectangle rect = rectObject.getRectangle();
            shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
            shapeRenderer.rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
            shapeRenderer.end();
        }
    }
    //done drawing rectangles
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
}

@Override
public void show(){
    //call the tile map here
    //I believe this is called first before render() is called
    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("data/mapComplete.tmx");
    mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap, 1f);

    //initiate shapeRenderer. Can remove later
    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should center the `camera` at the `viewport` of the game.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
    camera.position.set(width/2f, height/2f, 0); //by default camera position on (0,0,0)
}
```

Comment: but this doesnt center at the center of the map. It centers at the `viewport` center. If those are the same it's fine else this wouldnt be the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You do not set the position of the camera anywhere. Thus it is looking at (0, 0) by default (which means (0, 0) will be in the center of your screen). The TiledMapRenderer renders the bottom left corner of the map at (0, 0) which means that it will fill the top right quadrant of your screen. That's what you see in your screenshot.

To set it to the center of the map, you could do something like the following:

```
TiledMapTileLayer layer0 = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0);
Vector3 center = new Vector3(layer0.getWidth() * layer0.getTileWidth() / 2, layer0.getHeight() * layer0.getTileHeight() / 2, 0);
camera.position.set(center);
```

Comment: hello, can you tell me why is the (0,0) default position of camera is located at the center of the screen? thanks